# Proving union of two sets equal to union of other two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was studying set theory briefly and a question came into my mind . I questioned myself that what would be the condition for sets A, B, C and D to be related as - $A \cup B = C \cup D $ if they all are distinct sets.

Thinking upon this I finally came up with conditions for the given relation to hold true, which were -$$ B \cap C \neq \phi$$ $$ A \cap D \neq \phi$$ $$ A \cup D \subset B \cup D $$

I have no idea whether my conditions are incomplete or may be more than required. I just arrived at it by looking into examples of set unions. Also I wonder whether these are even significant.

So I want to know the validity of my conditions ( I couldn't find counter examples) and whether these could be of any significance later.

Thanks for your help

Comment: $\{1,2,3\}\cup \emptyset = \{1\}\cup \{2,3\}$, so your first and third condition fail with this example

Comment: Thanks. I didn't tried it with $ \phi $. So the conditions are invalid... Thanks again ...

Comment: If $A:=\left\{1,2\right\}$, $B:=\left\{3,4,5\right\}$, $C:=\left\{1\right\}$, $D:=\left\{2,3,4,5\right\}$ then $A\cup B=C\cup D$ but $B\cap C = \emptyset$ and also $A\cup D = \left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}\not\subset B\cup D = \left\{2,3,4,5\right\}$

Comment: I can now see how ignorant I was. Thanks all of you.

Comment: If you were looking at this from the other direction, trying to prove that given those three conditions that $A\cup B=C\cup D$ follows., this is again false if you take $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,2,3\},C=\{3,4\},D=\{1,4\}$, since despite all three of your conditions being met you have$\{1,2\}\cup \{1,2,3\}\neq \{3,4\}\cup \{1,4\}$

Comment: A set of conditions which *does* work would be $A\subseteq C\cup D, B\subseteq C\cup D, C\subseteq A\cup B, D\subseteq A\cup B$, but I don't find this any more pleasant to look at than the original way in which it was phrased

Comment: Another tip: The symbol for the empty set is `\emptyset` or `\varnothing`.